# What is special about the executables compiled with Visual Studio 11 which results in that the executables cannot be executed on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-xp, compatibility, visual-studio-2012

I compile my C++ source code with Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. I statically link to the runtime library.

The resulting executable cannot be executed on Windows XP. When I try to execute it on Windows XP I get the error message "[Executable Path] is not a valid Win32 Application.".

[According to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690617) Visual Studio 11 won't support Windows XP.

How does it work that the resulting executable cannot be executed on Windows XP? Is there anything special within the executable?

Comment: Which project type you use in VS2011 for your application ?

Comment: I use a Win32 Project and create a Win32 Application.

Comment: It is a 32 bit App. The result of dumpbin is:
Dump of file [Path]

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

        3000 .data
        3000 .rdata
        2000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        6000 .text

Comment: Shall I use different commandline options for dumpbin?

Comment: @Norbert Willhelm: You probably don't use fibers, what if you create your own fake version of this function?

Comment: @Anders How does creating a fake version of this function work?

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm: The page I linked to replaces some functions...

Comment: [Related question for VS2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20061248/145173)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They seem to drop support for older systems in every new release of VS (NT4,2000,[XP](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690617)) Even if you don't use the CRT at all, they still force the PE subsystem version to high numbers. You can work around that by [changing the numbers back](http://louis.steelbytes.com/vs2008_vs_win40.html) to 5.0 in a post build step. Just changing those numbers should allow the exe to start on XP unless the new CRT is using WinAPI functions that don't exist on XP.

The other alternative if you want to keep using VS11 is to use multi-targeting and older compilers...

Comment: I show you what functions are missing (for both CRT and MFC) and how to work around the fact that these functions are missing on XP at this blog post: http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/how-to-get-visual-c-2012-vc-11-beta-statically-linked-crt-and-mfc-applications-to-run-on-windows-xp/

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2012 will be able to target Windows XP later in 2012:

[Targeting Windows XP with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx)

*"Later this fall, Microsoft will provide an update to Visual Studio 2012 that will enable C++ applications to target Windows XP. This update will make the necessary modifications to the Visual C++ 2012 compiler, runtime, and libraries to enable developers to create applications and DLLs that run on Windows XP and higher versions as well as Windows Server 2003 and higher."*

**Edit**: This has now happened (phew!)

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to use a different `Platform Toolset`, which will link a different version of CRT and produce binaries compatible to older operating systems.

See more here: [Target Windows XP in Visual Studio 11 Beta using the Visual Studio 2010 compiler and libraries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/18/10295093.aspx).

With `v90` toolset your binary will be able to run even in older systems, such as Windows 2000.

http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-65-69/7444.BlogPic.png

Answer (score 1):

The runtime libraries bundled with VS 2010 and higher enforce your executable to import two new functions from kernel32.dll that are missing on Windows XP: `EncodePointer` and `DecodePointer`. Those are needed for yet another <s>idiotic</s> naive attempt to enhance the software "security".

In VS 2010 there is an option to use the runtime libraries of Visual Studio 2008, which solves this problem. I don't know if there's such an option in later versions of VS.

Comment: This is one reason. But it is not the only one.