# Backwards compatibility from Windows 95

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, backwards-compatibility

I am targeting a very poor demographic, where there is a wide range of Microsoft Windows platforms from Win95 to the most recent Windows 10.

I have read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [another](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070411-00/?p=27283) where they both explained how to use WINVER and other defines to ensure backwards compatibility. However, they did not go backwards far enough to address my compatibility requirements. Is there anyway to select an earlier version of Windows, preferably following a similar process to that discussed in the articles?

I know there are many considerations that I must take into account when creating the following software, such as defining my own entry point because Windows 95 does not have C runtime initialisation, but this question just wants to address the above.

Comment: Why do you assume that `WINVER` does *"not go backwards far enough"*? The second linked article explicitly points out, that a value of `0x0400` refers to Windows 95 (as well as Windows NT 4).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495232) they say the latest Visual C++ capable of targeting Windows 95 is VS 2005

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ program compatible with Windows 95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910974/c-program-compatible-with-windows-95)

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.