# 32bit Build in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I read in another thread that in order to make exe applications run on a 32bit OS, you need to go into the properties of your program and change Target CPU to x86. I've done this and for some reason, I still get an invalid win32 error when I try running it in Windows XP. I would post a picture but I don't have enough rep, so I hope you get what I'm trying to say!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had your exact same problem, take a look here [How to compile for Win XP with Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130713/how-to-compile-for-win-xp-with-visual-studio-2012)

Basically, VS 2012 does not support Windows XP, so you need to download & install [CTP Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34818) if you want your program to work in that OS.

Once installed, you need to change this option in your project properties:

[image: Project Properties]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, I just installed the update, but I'm having trouble finding the window you have a screenshot of. Where did you go to get that? My properties window doesn't look like that.

Comment: @Joshua Open up the Solution Explorer if it isn't (View -> Solution Explorer). From there, right click on the name of your project and click Properties. The window I posted previosly should show up. The option you need to find is in Configuration Properties -> General Tab.

Comment: You are talking about the C++ IDE, the OP is talking about one of the managed IDEs.

Comment: Also include PSAPI_VERSION=1 as a preprocessor definition to enable the XP Support .

Comment: Thx for your answer, picture is a very great idea! :)