# The procedure entry point `GetTickCount64` could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc, windows-xp

I created an *MFC* app on *Windows 8* using **Visual Studio 2012 Update 3**. It works on *Windows 8*, but on *Windows XP*, it shows me the following error:

`The procedure entry point GetTickCount64 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll`

I searched for a solution, but it was said that *Update 3* has fixed the problem with *Windows XP*. I downloaded and installed it, but it didn't help.
However, before installing the update, I was having a worse error!

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: What was that "worde" error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function does not exist in XP. In the documentation for the function it says "To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0600 or later." (That means Vista and newer.)  If you do that the app will  not run on XP.

Answer (score 1):

You should download Visual Studio Update 1 or later. Then you can target Windows XP

See here:
[How to compile for Win XP with Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130713/how-to-compile-for-win-xp-with-visual-studio-2012)