# Qt application on Windows XP and GetTickCount64

Tags: windows, qt, windows-xp

We have a problem with our Qt application on Windows XP. After VisualStudio and Qt update, we're getting following error:

```
The procedure entry point GetTickCount64 could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll
```

We have latest Qt 4.8.5 downloaded directly from Qt-project site. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://blog.inventic.eu/2013/08/gettickcount64-problem-on-windowsxp/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842981/the-procedure-entry-point-gettickcount64-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-l)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this 
     #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600

I think this is a visual studio problem, try this:

To target Windows XP:
1.  In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for your project, and then choose Properties.
2.  In the Property Pages dialog box for the project, under Configuration Properties, General, set the Platform Toolset property to Visual Studio 2012 – Windows XP (v110_xp).

Comment: I solved it by defining WINVER=0x0501 and _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 like described in this [blog](http://blog.inventic.eu/2013/08/gettickcount64-problem-on-windowsxp/)

Answer (score -2):

i think that it is problem about your service pack or visual studio version problem .Try to redesingn the visual c++ reconate component.