# C++ Visual Studio .exe not working in other computers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've created a very crude C++ console based Win32 application and released it in Visual Studio 2012 Express. I use a Windows 7 and when I try to open it in my brother's Windows XP computer it tells me that it isn't a valid Win32 application. Uhm, help?

Comment: You will need to deploy the appropriate runtime, perhaps: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile for Win XP with Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130713/how-to-compile-for-win-xp-with-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the appropriate dependencies for the operating system on that computer, i.e. C runtime, MFC, etc. in order for it to run there. You can also compile for Min Dependency and statically link MFC (if you are using that) to limit the redistributable problem.

Here is a link to the redistributables for VS 2012:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Does that help?