# Compile with msbuild msvc2012 on Windows XP

Tags: msbuild, windows-xp, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 2012 (and 2013 now) cannot be installed on Windows XP but I've seen there is an option to target compilation to XP.
I don't have Windows XP and I would know : Is it possible to compile c++ using msbuild.exe from visual studio 2012 ?
I know XP is not supported but we have always machine working on this OS and want to do that.
And what about the the xp targetting option, it's working fine ?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's not possible, msbuild and the compiler and linker won't run on XP either.  Time to get that machine updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile for Win XP with Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130713/how-to-compile-for-win-xp-with-visual-studio-2012)