# Targeting Windows XP in MFC application using Visual Studio 2013/2015 onward

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I've created a simple `MFC` application through `visual studio 2013` 32-bit.
Then when tested on Windows XP I find it does not work, and display an error message `the application is not a valid win32 application`.

Note that the application works fine in Windows 7.

**What's wrong ?**

Comment: @willll: 32Bit application.

Comment: @LionKing : http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx "Requires Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later."

Comment: @willll unfortunately that link doesn't have any information about how to configure a native C++ app for WinXP. It only claims it is possible.

Comment: You might find an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061248/compiled-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-will-not-work-with-wi.

Comment: @willll: I already have updated to update 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who wants a direct solution, try to apply the following steps.

**Steps:**

1. Right-click on the project and select properties.
2. General.
3. Platform Toolset.
4. Select Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp).

[image]

Also, you can see this MSDN article, [Windows XP Targeting with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx?PageIndex=2) for more help.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Intel has an article, [Linking Applications using Visual Studio 2012 or later to Run on Windows XP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linking-applications-using-visual-studio-2012-to-run-on-windows-xp) describing the same procedure. For Visual Studio 2012 it looks like a Service Pack is also needed.